# Couldn't read directory: Permission denied when using AWS SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, amazon-iam

I am trying to set up a simple AWS SFTP server with a scoped-down policy but keep getting permission denied errors when trying to `put` and `get`.

Here is IAM Role with generic S3 bucket access:

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::SOME-EXAMPLE-BUKCET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOME-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the scoped-down policy which I attach to the user when I create it in the SFTP panel:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeBucket}",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${transfer:UserName}/*",
                        "${transfer:UserName}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOME-EXAMPLE-BUCKET"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeDirectory}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeDirectory}*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The goal is for a user to log in and land in their home directory with read/write/delete permissions for just that directory. I've tried various policies from the following links but never quite get what I need:

[Connecting to AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642132/connecting-to-aws-transfer-for-sftp/54132370#54132370)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/users.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/requirements-roles.html

I always either get no access at all and everything is denied (i.e. can't even `ls`). Or I can `ls` but can't do anything else like `mkdir, put, get,` etc...

Comment: did you solve this problem? Can you accept an answer if so, or post your own answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scoped-down policy, why do you use transfer:UserName in the ListBucket condition rather than transfer:HomeDirectory like in the Put/Get/DeleteObject statement? Is the HomeDirectory of the user the same as its username?

What happens when you try something like this?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeBucket}",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${transfer:HomeDirectory}/*",
                        "${transfer:HomeDirectory}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::SOME-EXAMPLE-BUCKET"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeDirectory}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeDirectory}*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use ${transfer:Username} in the scoped down policy. Also, make sure you specify it as Policy key within secrets manager.

I have documented the full setup here in case you need to reference it - https://coderise.io/sftp-on-aws-with-username-and-password/